# Dynamically Android Activity Layout using SQL Database

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am asked to build a survey application on Android that may contain questions from the users, the question might be changed after some time and their answers as well.
the nature of answer might get in form of radio, checkboxes, drop-down or plain text.

I want to do this through SQL database. it will get the question from Master table and answer Option(s) from detail table and dynamically designs the activity layout accordingly.

Is that possible or is there any other way to do the same.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You can build the layouts programmatically.

Comment: i need to know how

Comment: Using classes like LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, Button and so on. You try to build a specific view so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in many ways. You can create custom views for each type of layout and inflate the required view based on the type question you fetch from the Database.
You can also just use simple XML layouts instead of the custom views. The benefit of using custom views will be that you can predefine events and other things within the view which makes it easy to reuse.

Here are a couple of tutorials to give you an idea. 
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCustomViews/article.html#tutorial_compoundcontrols3
https://www.intertech.com/Blog/android-custom-view-tutorial-part-1-combining-existing-views/

Answer (score 0):

In all honesty you're not going to get any answer on here that provides you with nearly enough detail for how to do this if you're not sure how to start. It's simple to breakdown but a lot more complex than you realise.

However.. essentially you need to:

- Create a DB table that contains questions.
- Create a DB table that contains potential answers options. If answers
  can be used for multiple questions, consider handling this
  appropriately.
- The question table should contain a column that details the question
  type, i.e. radio button, checkbox etc...
- The question table should link to another table which provides links
  to the potential answers.

The above really needs to be well designed before you code anything. Think it through thoroughly and only use the above as a guide.

Your UI should be dynamic. Use something such as list/recycler view that will allow you to insert rows of data. You can then create XML layouts for checkbox answers, radio answers and insert these as appropriate.

Again, you need to consider, will you display all questions/answers in a list, will they be displayed one by one and moved onto... in a wizard style approach.

As I say, you will not get a fully detailed answer because a lot of this isn't coding, it's thinking and designing.

I hope the above helps you to get a rough and basic understanding of what you need to do and how to approach it. Don't be under any illusion that this is going to be quick to do. Spend quite a bit of time before coding to design this, because, coding it is easy... the design which is the most important part here is what will take the time.

Answer (score 0):

I have done one project that consists only dynamic questions and answers like you.First You have to create Layout programmatically.

```
 RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout();
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Add your rule to that layout.

```
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
```

Then create your view and then set properties like below.

```
EditText edittext = new EditText()
editext.setId(1);
editext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT); 
editext.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
```

Thats' all you created a view programmatically. Then you can add to you child to the parent view.

```
layout.addView(edittext);
```

You can create multiple layouts and multiple views by doing this. just think about it. Don't forget to add your child Layout to your parent Layout. Keep coding..